# SonarQube showing Cognitive Complexity error Even there is only 7 loops

Tags: sonarqube

I am review my code using SonarQube. I am receiving the following issue.

**Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 21 to the 15 allowed.**

But my method contains only 7 loops. Herewith I attached the code.

```
private void LayoutTouch(int touchType, int index) {

        if (touchType != -1) { //+1
            try {
                ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(ctContext);
                mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
                parentLayout[index]
                        .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v,
                                                   MotionEvent event) {
                                if(!isValidEvent()){ //+2
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if(checkTouchIndex(index)){ //+3
                                    try{
                                        
                                        // Code here

                                        if (animationStarted) { //+4
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration
                                                .get(getContext());
                                        final int deltaX = (int) (event.getX() + 0.5f)
                                                - mGestureCurrentX;


                                        initiateVelocityTracker();
                                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);

                                        mVelocityTracker
                                                .computeCurrentVelocity(1000);

                                        if(!doSwitchAndNeedToReturn(v, event, index, vc, deltaX)) // +5
                                            return false;
                                    }catch(Exception e){ //+6
                                        setTouchProgressIndex(-1);
                                    }finally{
                                        setTouchProgressIndex(-1);
                                    }
                                }

                                return false;
                            }

                        });

            } catch (Exception e) { //+7
                Log.e("Testing","Exception "+ e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why I am getting this issue. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with SonarQube that the code is overly complex.

Simplifications possible:

- combine if statements
- use a lambda
- (not done here) use an extra method for the lambda code

So:

```
private void LayoutTouch(int touchType, int index) {

    if (touchType != -1) { //+1
        try {
            ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(ctContext);
            mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
            parentLayout[index]
                    .setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
                            if (isValidEvent() && checkTouchIndex(index)) {
                                try{
                                    
                                    // Code here

                                    if (animationStarted) { //+4
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration
                                            .get(getContext());
                                    final int deltaX = (int) (event.getX() + 0.5f)
                                            - mGestureCurrentX;


                                    initiateVelocityTracker();
                                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);

                                    mVelocityTracker
                                            .computeCurrentVelocity(1000);

                                    if (!doSwitchAndNeedToReturn(v, event, index, vc, deltaX)) // +5
                                        return false;
                                } catch(Exception e) { //+6
                                    setTouchProgressIndex(-1);
                                } finally {
                                    setTouchProgressIndex(-1);
                                }
                            }

                            return false;
                        });

        } catch (Exception e) { //+7
            Log.e("Testing","Exception "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

The extra method:

```
                    .setOnTouchListener(this::onTouch);

private boolean onTouch(View v,  MotionEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

The checked exception handling is very unspecific. If not a specific exception can happen, maybe drop it (at the end).

Using member variables named with the prefix m, is not conventional in java. These variables indeed seem many, but with mouse, touch and so that might make sense.
I mention this, as the calculations seem refactorable.

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave many ideas to improve myself.

Answer (score 1):

> But my method contains only 7 loops

Sonar is telling you that the method is hard to understand (cognitive complexity). And I do agree with the criteria. The complexity does not grow linearly and that is why it goes +1, +2, +3, +4 +5 +6 +7 = 28 > 21.

As a developer I would really want this piece of code cleaned up. Here are some suggestions:

- Extract the OnTouchListener into a class (inner or not)
- Change the initial check as a guard condition with an early return.
- Review why are you doing the same thing in finally and the exception. `setTouchProgressIndex(-1)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, This need to be improve in my code and myself.